# creating selenium tests on chromeOS

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-os

I currently have a java project which instantiates various browsers via selenium hub/node on various windows operating systems. Is there much involved to expand this to cater for running up a browser on a stock chromebook chromeOS?

Answer (score 0):

The following are steps I tried back in November 2014. The result was unsuccessful and I [opened a question on the Google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/jJMPF2DJ-MQ) with no response.

- followed manufacturer's instructions to put the Chromebook in Developer Mode
- set chromeos-firrmwareupdate to dev mode and removed rootfs verification from partitions 2 and 4
- downloaded and installed Java (latest jre), required for Jenkins slave and Selenium
- downloaded Jenkins slave.jar and selenium-server-standalone.jar (2.41.0)
  put Jenkins and Selenium in /home and remounted to remove noexec
- remounted tmp to resize to 2G (req for Jenkins)
- added DISPLAY=:0.0 to ui.conf to set display
- added chain rule to allow tcp input
- added 'no-sandbox' and 'disable-setuid-sandbox' switches and excluded 'test-type' switch

Result: ChromeDriver started up, opened up a gray screen (a broken instance of Chrome), and closed with an "unable to open pages" error. Weird thing, though, was that the same command used to launch Chrome worked when run from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed information. Perhaps at some point I'll return to trying to test Chrome OS. For now, I'm automating a windows chrome browser (logged into the browser account) and extension file, in place of a chromeOS and extension file. I'm sure these steps will be useful to others who attempt to embark on ChromeOS automation at some point. So thanks again.